# How to bind param multiple times with MySQLI?

Tags: php, mysql, binding, mysqli, param

This is how I'm binding my params:

```
$Con = mysqli_connect(...);
$Statement = mysqli_stmt_init($Con);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($Statement,"select * from users where name=? and email=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s",$Username);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s",$Email); <-- it fails here
```

But it works fine in the other case when I replace the 2 calls to mysqli_stmt_bind_param with:

```
mysql_stmt_bind_param("ss",$Username,$Email)
```

The problem is that I have an array of params; I have to bind them one by one coz I don't know the number of params

Comment: Do you *have* to use MySQLi? The PDO binding syntax is much more intuitive

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A bit offtopic but I find it important enough.

A very recent user comment in the manual page for mysql_stmt_bind_param contains the exact answer to this very question.

You see, this site, although encourage laziness, not always answer your question better than good old google and manual can.

Comment: i thinking of generating php code for binding then call 'eval', but call_user_func_array really solves the problem much better, tks col

Comment: there doesn't even exist a function `mysql_stmt_bind_param`. [this one](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) does.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree - I always go for the SO answer over the manual because of the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach does not work because the right way to use the mysqli_stmt_bind_param  is precisely follow:

```
mysql_stmt_bind_param("ss",$Username,$Email)
```

refs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

to know the number of parameters makes a count() array.

Answer (score 4):

MySQLi's statement binding really isn't suited to variable numbers of parameters.

I highly recommend switching to PDO

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from users where name=? and email=?');
$stmt->execute($numericArrayOfParameters);
```